# Death penalty by kings in sanathan dharma

Tags: scripture, punishment

It is clear from the story of Kalmashapada that executioning exist as a punishment for bad humans in sanathan dharma

> "The Gandharva continued, 'Thus commanded, the cook went out in search
> of meat. Distressed at not having found any, he informed the king of
> his failure. The monarch, however, possessed as he was by the
> Rakshasa, repeatedly said, without scruple of any kind, 'Feed him with
> human flesh.' The cook, saying, 'So be it,' **went to the place where
> the (king's) executioners were,** and thence taking human flesh and
> washing and cooking it duly and covering it with boiled rice offered
> it unto that hungry Brahmana devoted to ascetic penances.
>
> [[section 178, Chaitraratha Parva,   Adi Parva, The Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01179.htm)

But this story clues only about the existence of the death penalty and does not have elaboration on the methods followed etc.,

Are there any mentions or stories in scriptures about how the death penalty is implemented by executioners?

Comment: You want to know what methods were used?

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, either explicit methods or story mentioning those. Any way is fine.